# Selenium PageFactory: initelements once per class?

Tags: java, selenium, pageobjects

This is likely to be more of a java question than selenium, but since I am very new to Java I don't know the answer.  I am writing selenium tests using the page object model.  I have the pages in one class, and the tests in another.  However, I am trying to only execute `PageFactory.initelements` once per test class so I don't have to add the line in each test (in that class, anyways,  I want to do something like this:

```
import com.company.pages.LoginPage

public class LoginTests {

    LoginPage login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class );

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        login.method();
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        login.methodTwo();
    }
}
```

But I keep getting a `NullPointerException` on an object I defined in the `LoginPage` class.  That tells me that the page was never initialized.  But since I am relatively new to Java, I don't know how to initialize it.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
LoginPage login;

@Before
public void beforeTest() {
    login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class );
}
```

According to [this](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Before.html):

> Annotating a public void method with @Before causes that method to be
>   run before the Test method.

This will help in cutting down the verbosity of your tests.

Comment: That actually did not work, but it led me to the answer.  I have my driver definitions in another class using TestNG's `@BeforeMethod`, so I added another `@BeforeMethod` in the actual test class that gets executed after the first one, and put the code there!

Answer (score 1):

Whichever the variable you have declared need to be initialized to an value.

`int a;        // This is a declaration
 a = 0;        // This is an initialization
 int b = 0;    // This is a declaration and initialization`

In terms of pageObejcts, considering Homepage as a class,you can initialize webelement as below

```
private static WebElement element = null;
```

Comment: Thank you.  I understand that.  I'm saying that I *thought* I initialized the `LoginPage`  class at the top of the class, but I still got the error.

Comment: The point of `PageFactory.initElements` is that I shouldn't need to initialize individual elements, but instead initialize the page and get the elements with the page.  If I include `LoginPage login = PageFactory.initElements(driver, LoginPage.class)` in each `@Test`, the code works with no issues.  I was just hoping to initialize the page only once per class and cut down on the verbosity of the tests.